# Como incrementar o index de um array ilimitado?

Tags: c, array, struct, auto-incremento

Como é que eu posso incrementar um array dentro de uma estrutura?

A minha estrutura é esta:

```
struct list {
char name[50];
int products_list[]; } LIST[10];
```

Eu queria saber o número atual de elementos no array (produtos_lista) para adiconar mais produtos com o index certo.

O meu problema é: Eu uso o scanf para obter os produtos do utilizador, para que estes possam ser ilimitados.
Eu tentei usar a função sizeof mas não funcionou porque não adicionou direito os index's dos produtos.

```
posicao_atual = (sizeof(LISTA[opcao_lista].produtos_listas) / sizeof(int) + 1);
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Ah, e por sinal o que te impede de colocar um contador do tipo `int` dentro da estrutura para dizer quantos são os itens preenchidos?

Comment: O meu problema é que tenho varias listas de compras.
O utilizador pode inserir 3 produtos numa, sair da área de inserção de produtos e voltar a qualquer momento. É ai nessa altura que eu preciso de saber, que exatamente naquela lista existem 3 produtos. Com o contador ia incrementar para qualquer lista.

Comment: Tenta penar mais no problema. Qual seu objetivo no final de tudo isso?

Comment: Ué, é só criar uma função para adicionar itens na lista, recebendo ela como parâmetro e o item a ser adicionado. Ai então, você incrementa a variável que indica a quantidade e insere. Lembro de ter feito listas desse tipo na disciplina de Estrutura de Dados, e este problema era solucionado assim.

Comment: @AntónioFreitas as duas contas são suas, certo? Quer que juntemos elas? Qual das duas deve sobreviver?

Answer (score 1):

inclua uma variável com o tamanho da lista: `unsigned int product_list_size`.

```
typedef struct {
    char name [50];
    unsigned int product_list_size;
    int products_list [];
} list_t;

// ...

list_t list [10];
list.product_list_size = 0;
// Inicialização da lista...
```

Quando for incluir um novo produto, incremente o contador. `list_number` é o número da lista.

```
list [list_number].product_list_size++;
```

**Opção 1 de Contagem**

Utilize este contador para a alocação de memória. Se for retirar um produto da lista é só decrementar e realizar a alocação dos produtos nas novas posições.

**Opção 2 de Contagem**

Ao excluir um item da lista, configure a como `-1` (`position` é a posição do produto na lista), sem decrementar o `product_list_size`. Não será necessário realocar a memória.

```
list [list_number].products_list [position] = -1;
```

Para contar é só percorrer a lista e descartar os valores negativos

```
unsigned int product_list_size = 0;

for (unsigned int _position; _position < list [list_number].product_list_size; _position++) {
    if (list [list_number].products_list [_position] > 0)
        product_list_size++;
```

Não se esqueça que o tamanho máximo da lista será o tamanho máximo do inteiro, de acordo com a plataforma.